# How do I structure my databases to avoid inserting arrays? (Variable number of records)

Tags: mysql, database

I currently have 3 tables, but I am unsure of how to structure the last of them (Recipe Table).  The **Users Table** holds basic information about each user's account and account settings. The **Ingredients Table** lists each item a user has (or used to have) in their possession. The **Recipe Table** contains the users' recipes and contains information on what, how much, and the preparation of each ingredient, as well as numbered steps to carry out the recipe.  Both the number of ingredients and steps are variable and up to the user before DB insertion.

Ingredients: AMOUNT in UNITS of **IngredientID**, HOWPREPARED1, HOWPREPARED2

As well as...

Cooking instructions: COOKINGSTEP# - INSTRUCTIONS

Where each ingredient MUST be referenced by the IngredientID found in the **Ingredients Table**.

**Is there a feasible way to do this so that:**

A. Is efficient and won't force too many database calls?
B. Does not violate any of the rules of normalization?

### Users Table

- UserID
- Username
- Password
- Salt
- Email
- Etc...

### Ingredients Table

- IngredientID
- UserID
- Name
- FoodGroup
- Picture
- InStock
- Etc...

### Recipe Table

- RecipeID
- UserID
- ???

Comment: I *think* that I need to create a recipe_ingredients table as well as a recipe_cookingsteps table.  Where both have unique IDs and reference the recipe's ID that they are used in.

OR

I can save the cooking instructions in a blob or text field, but force formatting at user input. However, a recipe_ingredients table would still be needed.

Can someone confirm or deny this for me? And if this works, is there a better method?

Comment: You can have a link table, that links ingredients against recipes (possibly also containing the amount of that ingredient for a particular recipe). You could also have a table of recipe steps, with multiple rows for each recipe.